# JQuery Move Screen to specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a JQuery UI dialog with a link in it. When the link is clicked, the dialog should close then move the screen/client window down the to footer div that contains contact details.

**My Problem:** The screen never moves to where I tell it to, it just stays where it is. The dialog closes correctly(so I know the javascript function is being called) but the client area doesn't scroll-down/move/switch to the footer element. Information: the footer is at the base of the page & the page(body element) is about 2000px high.

What am I doing wrong & how can I get the screen to move the a certain element?

```
function moveToFooter()
{
    $("body").scrollTop($("#footer").position().left+$("#footer").offset().left, $("#footer").position().top+$("#footer").offset().top);
    // Just a simple test to move the screen anywhere doesn't work either:
    $("body").scrollTop(300,2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[scrollTop](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/dimensions/scrollTop) only takes one argument, the horizontal position.  You're giving it two.

Also, your adding the CSS position to the offset position of the footer.  That doesn't make any sense.  For absolutely positioned elements, it might make a little sense, but not much.

So, the correct code should be

```
function moveToFooter() {
    $("body").scrollTop($("#footer").offset().top);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scrollTop` only takes one argument i.e top position. For left or X position use `scrollLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use both `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft` to move the page, since `scrollTop` only changes the ***Y*** axle.

### Plugin

---

There is a great plugin that I am using it.
[***jQuery.ScrollTo***](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html), created by Ariel Flesler.
You can easily move the screen to where you want, which element you want, and also offsets.
There's also a amazing [**demo page**](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) for it.

Comment: Seriously, please stop using KBD formatting inappropriately. It has been [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181774/stricter-kbd-usage-rules) if you're interested in reading.